# Is a header added/removed at each layer of the OSI model?

Tags: networking, tcp, ip, protocols, osi

I'm trying to understand the relationship between the OSI and TCP/IP models, and read at the following link that in the OSI model, one header is added/removed at each layer:

https://www.electronicdesign.com/what-s-difference-between/what-s-difference-between-osi-seven-layer-network-model-and-tcpip

That article breaks down the headers that are added/removed at each layer of the TCP/IP model, and it looks like there is one added at each layer.

What I want to know is:

I've read that both the OSI and TCP/IP models are theoretical; in what way are they theoretical and in what way are they each physically accurate? For example, the Applications layer of TCP/IP corresponds to the Application/Presentation/Session layers of OSI; is the header for the Applications TCP/IP layer comprised of three components, each of which is considered the header for Application/Presentation/Session layers of OSI?

Answer (score 2):

The article is misleading. It is not true that each layer is simply adding a header.

Each layer is doing some kind of encapsulation of the layer above. For the layers 3 and 4 this encapsulation is done with a header at least when these two layers are IP and UDP/TCP. But the encapsulation at these layers also includes fragmentation of the content, i.e. spreading of large data over multiple packets.

Application layer encapsulation or encryption of the communication is way more complex than a simple header and depends on the specific application layer or encryption protocol.

> in what way are they theoretical and in what way are they each physically accurate?

These are a model only. This means that they are simplified abstractions of the reality. While they kind of accurately describe the layers 2..4 especially the OSI models layer 5..7 does not match today's reality. At the time these models were created the network world was much more simpler and the layers 5..7 in the OSI model looked like a useful approach to develop protocols.

But in reality session, presentation and application is all mixed together in today's protocols: in case of HTTPS content is transferred with the HTTP protocol which then is inside a TLS tunnel but the tunnel might be again inside a SOCKS tunnel or even initiated with a HTTP CONNECT request (HTTP proxy). And a kind of layer 4 protocol like WebSockets is essentially tunneled within a Layer 7 protocol HTTP etc. There are even design where TLS records are exchanged as JSON inside a HTTPS connection.

This means that TCP/IP protocol fits more today's reality simply because it is simpler and does not have some envisioned abstraction layers which turned out not to be used.

Comment: Hi Steffen, thanks for your reply. So is it correct to say that in different scenarios with different networks infrastructure and different operations over that network, the steps that occur vary from one scenario to the next, and the distinct layers of each model encompass what 'tends' to happen during different phases of data transfer? For example, if you're sending an email vs making an HTTP request, each operation entails a different set of preliminary steps, but they can all be abstracted as 'application layer' steps. Am I on the right track?

Comment: @gkeenley: network infrastructure is mostly relevant for the transport of the data, i.e. mostly layer 1..3. Application layer is instead mostly relevant for (surprise) applications (likely what you mean with "operations") since these handle the application protocols: a web server deals with HTTP and HTTPS, mail servers with SMTP, IMAP, POP3 (and their TLS encapsulations), database have their own access protocols too etc. There are some things like load balancers which can work at layer 7 but might be considered part of network infrastructure.